# jakarta.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager- weld tomcat 10 and JSF 3, JDK11

Tags: tomcat, jsf, cdi, jboss-weld, tomcat10

I am to set up a Skeleton  with AdoptOpenJDK 11, tomcat 10.0.8, Jakarta EE9, weld and primefaces 10 jsf I have seen several posts regarding this issue and have tried all the fixes but do not seem to be able to get this to work and the project will not start.
I keep getting the following:

```
08-Jul-2021 11:30:33.917 INFO [http-nio-8095-exec-10] org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener.onStartup WELD-ENV-001008: Initialize Weld using ServletContainerInitializer
08-Jul-2021 11:30:33.964 INFO [http-nio-8095-exec-10] org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.<clinit> WELD-000900: 4.0.1 (Final)
08-Jul-2021 11:30:34.116 WARN [http-nio-8095-exec-10] org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.WeldServletLifecycle.initialize WELD-ENV-000028: Weld initialization skipped - no bean archive found
08-Jul-2021 11:30:34.116 INFO [http-nio-8095-exec-10] org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener.contextInitialized WELD-ENV-001006: org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.EnhancedListener used to initialize Weld
08-Jul-2021 11:30:34.174 INFO [http-nio-8095-exec-10] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Initializing Mojarra 3.0.1 for context '/test'
08-Jul-2021 11:30:34.304 INFO [http-nio-8095-exec-10] com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory.createInstance JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans methods marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
08-Jul-2021 11:30:35.165 SEVERE [http-nio-8095-exec-10] com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized Critical error during deployment: 
    jakarta.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager
        at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.tryAddCDIELResolver(ELUtils.java:297)
        at com.sun.faces.el.ELUtils.buildFacesResolver(ELUtils.java:227)
        at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationAssociate.initializeELResolverChains(ApplicationAssociate.java:463)
        at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.performOneTimeELInitialization(ExpressionLanguage.java:183)
        at com.sun.faces.application.applicationimpl.ExpressionLanguage.getELResolver(ExpressionLanguage.java:122)
```

my pom is:

```
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.chemnetbase</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject4</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>mavenproject4-1.0</name>
    
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        <jakartaee>9.1.0</jakartaee>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jakartaee}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
 

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-servlet-shaded</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.0</version>
            <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
        </dependency>
        


        
       
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>11</source>
                    <target>11</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>${jakartaee}</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

beans.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<beans xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/beans_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">

</beans>
```

my faces-config.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-facesconfig_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0"
>
    <!-- Your faces config here. -->
</faces-config>
```

my context.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="">

<Resource name="BeanManager" 
        auth="Container"
        type="jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
        factory="org.jboss.weld.resources.ManagerObjectFactory"/>
   
</Context>
```

my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
  version="4.0"
  metadata-complete="true"
>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.jboss.weld.development</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>jakarta.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.jsp</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>        
    </session-config>
    <error-page>
        <exception-type>jakarta.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
        <location>/index.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/error.xhtml</location>
    </error-page>
   <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
         index.xhtml
        </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <resource-env-ref>
        <resource-env-ref-name>BeanManager</resource-env-ref-name>
        <resource-env-ref-type>
            jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager
        </resource-env-ref-type>
    </resource-env-ref>
</web-app>
```

I have placed my beans.xml in the WEB-INF folder:
[my project set up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tahqq.gif)

I have been looking at this for hours and cannot seem to find the issue.  If someone can give me some guidance it would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you

Comment: I  think I found what the issue was  the declartionin in the web.xml.  Seems to be working now!<web-app xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee
                      https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd"
  version="5.0"
  metadata-complete="true">

Comment: If this solves your problem, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found what the issue was, the declaration in the web.xml. Seems to be working now!`<web-app xmlns="jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd" version="5.0" metadata-complete="true">`